# for $\sigma$-finite Borel measures show that the measure of the diagonal $(\mu\times \upsilon)(\Delta)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}} \mu(\{x\})\upsilon(\{x\})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am trying to show that given two sigma-finite measure spaces $(\Bbb{R},B({\Bbb{R}}),\mu)$ $(\Bbb{R},B({\Bbb{R}}),\upsilon)$,and the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R^2}|x=y\}$, it holds that $(\mu\times \upsilon)(\Delta)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{R}} \mu(\{x\})\upsilon(\{x\})$
I need to know that my arguments are okay for this question.
Can I argue that if $E=\{x:\mu(\{x\})>0\},F=\{x:\upsilon(\{y\})>0\}$ (which I proved are at most countable), then $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{{\Bbb{R}\setminus E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)+\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=\int_{F}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)+\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus F}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=\int_{F}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)?$

Is it immediate, notation-wise, that $\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus F}\int_{{E}}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=\int_{{{E}}}\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus F}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\upsilon(y)d\mu(
x)=\int_{E}\upsilon(\Delta(x))d\mu(x)=0?$

My problem is showing that $\upsilon (\Delta(x))=\upsilon(\{x\})=0$ because I don't know how to get $\Bbb{R}\setminus F$ involved. Is it the case that $\int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus F}1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\upsilon(y)=\upsilon(\Delta(x)\cap F^c)?$

Comment: Yes, $\int_S 1_T (y)dv(y)=v(S\cap T)$.

Comment: why you assume that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{E^\complement }1_{\Delta}(x,y)d\mu(
x)d\upsilon(y)=0$? The set $(\mathbb{R}\times E^\complement )\cap \Delta =E^\complement \times E^\complement $ is still uncountable

Comment: I didn't, I only referred to integrals with either $E$ or $F$